# Google Maps not showing in a NativeScript app, but shows in a native app developed with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a NativeScript+Angular app that needs to show a map plus do some travel time calculations. Obviously, Google Maps is my main choice. I have created a new project in my Google Developer Console, created a new API Key for 2 APIs: Maps SDK for Android & the Distance Matrix API. Using that API Key, I tried to add code in my app, following the example shown in the [nativescript-google-maps-sdk](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk) GitHub repo. When I try to run the app in the emulator, I cannot see it:

[image: Simple NativeScript app not showing the Google Maps]

The component is properly loaded, because I see the "See map below!" label. Here is my component's HTML code:

```html
<ActionBar title="Map Demo" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout rows="auto, *">
    <Label row="0" text="See map below!"></Label>"
    <MapView row="1" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" iosOverflowSafeArea="true"></MapView>
</GridLayout>
```

My API Key is valid, because I tested it into a simple app created in the Android Studio and there, I can see the map:

[image: Android Studio native app showing the map]

Can anyone shed some light into what am I doing wrong? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eddie